# Is it ok to refer to node_modules directly?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, node-modules, yarnpkg

The project I'm currently working on (`Java`/`JSP`) currently uses no package manager to manage its `JavaScript` dependencies.

The used libraries are just committed under version control, and referred as such from the JSP pages...

I would like to evolve to a workflow were we would use a package manager (e.g. `yarn`), and later on eventually also `webpack` to further optimise the build.

I would like to do this in a phased approach. As I have little to none experience with such a *frontend workflow*, I have some questions:

1. Would it be weird to just start with defining the used libraries in a `package.json` file, and use `yarn` to manage to package?

`yarn` will then fetch the modules and store them in the `node_modules` folder.

2. Is it bad practice to refer to the scripts in that `node_modules` folder directly from within the JSP files?

### Example

*package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
}
```

*app.jsp*:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're using Maven, have you looked at [WebJars](https://www.webjars.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that's completely ok. It's the way we normally initialize frontend projects (probably sometimes, some higher-level script does it for us but still). Just run `npm init`.
2. Oh yes, that's quite bad. Most probably, it simply will not work. If you want to load something directly on a page, you need a cdn version.

To be honest, having a `package.json` is not that useful without a building tool like webpack, gulp or grunt.

**UPD**:
Regarding *why* loading things directly from `node_modules` might hurt:

A lot of modern JS packages (like, for instance, React) use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) that are not implemented yet in any browser or ES5+ syntax which is supported only by some browsers.

This way, you may load React directly but it will crash in any browser with something like `import is not defined`.

Basically, **a lot** of modern packages expect you to either have a building tool or use cdn version.

Honestly, I don't know how many packages let you seamlessly load things directly from `node_modules`.

So, in your particular situation, I'd say that if particular packages you use let you do so & are shipped with browser-compatible version, you can just go ahead & do it this way.

Nevertheless, I see it highly possible that sooner or later you will face a package that **will not** let you to include it this way (*or worse*: it will, but will crash some browsers that don't support latest JS features/introduce other nasty bugs in your app).

Hopefully, at this stage, you will already have the building tool configured.

**Bonus**:
Relatively recently some browsers started to [support modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)!

There are even tools like [snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) that do something particularly similar to what you are looking for.

Even though, you still need to be *very* careful with this. Direct inclusion of lodash.js, for instance, will generate 640 GETs (check out [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/) -> "Libraries" section).

Comment: As long as he's serving `node_modules` from the static resources, why would that script not work? It's debateable whether it's a good approach, but I could see it as a short term fix.

Comment: @TomG it might work still in some cases. I just have never seen a single library or resource that recommends doing so in my life. In particular case of [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) it might work. They don't specify any particular way to include it after install.

Comment: Well the question is not really _if_ it would work (it does, I tried ;-)), but rather if this is a good approach. I have the gut feeling _it isn't_, but cannot really quantify it

Comment: @IgorBykov, why would I need a CDN version? This is BTW not an option as the application we are working on is deployed on premise, and internet access is not guaranteed to be available...

Comment: @Ward I've just updated the answer to clarify my original points.

Comment: @Ward I've updated the answer another time since I recently get to know some interesting facts that might help you!

Answer (score -1):

NPM packages are meant to be run with Node, not in a browser. You would need to serve a browser-friendly version, using something like webpack or browserify.

Comment: That is not universally true. Dependencies such as JQuery are commonly packaged as UMD modules which can be consumed by the browser.